# Not receiving broadcast from intent sender in Android 10 when 'Copy' is selected

Tags: android, kotlin, android-10.0

I am trying to get callbacks in BroadcastReceiver from IntentSender when user completes a share action (whether copying url to clipboard or selecting any application)

I have followed the android documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send#share-interaction-data) on how to detect when users complete a share in Android Sharesheet. It is working fine for all Android below Android 10 but not for Android 10. In Android 10, my broadcast receiver is not being called when 'copy' is selected in a chooser (but it is still working fine if user selects other apps).

Does anyone know why or face the same problem? I am not sure if the issue is specific to some devices. I have tested this with Pixel2 And Huawei P30 (both with Android 10).

I have created my BroadcastReceiver like this:

```
class MyBroadCastReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
        //receiving broadcast here
    }
}
```

I have also declared my broadcast receiver in the manifest file:

```
<receiver
    android:name=".MyBroadCastReceiver"
    android:exported="false" />
```

Here is the code calling CreateChooser dialog:

```
val shareIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
shareIntent.type = "text/plain"
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareUrl)

val receiver = Intent(this, MyBroadCastReceiver::class.java)
val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, receiver, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
val intent = Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share url", pendingIntent.intentSender)
startActivity(intent)
```

Screenshot:
https://i.ibb.co/477JMPb/Screen-Shot-2563-04-12-at-09-01-10.png

Thanks.

Comment: It will be much easier to help you if you would provide a [mcve] showing how you are setting up your `PendingIntent` and how you are registering your `BroadcastReceiver`.

Comment: That certainly looks reasonable. As an experiment, try switching `android:exported="false"` to `android:exported="true"`. You should not need that, and it's not great from a security standpoint, but it is worth a test. Also, do you see anything interesting in Logcat after you make your share sheet selection (when the broadcast should be sent)? The message would be from the system, so make sure you are not filtering on just your process.

Comment: I tested switching android:exported="false" to android:exported="true", but the result is still the same.

Comment: I am not really sure if this would help but I have found this:
In normal case (selects any apps other than ‘copy’), after calling chooser dialog, ActivityTaskManager: START ChooserActivity. And after making a selection, ActivityTaskManager: START ChooserActivity -> MyBroadcastReceiver’s callback called -> ActivityTaskManager: START the selected application’s activity.

‘Copy’ case, after calling chooser dialog, ActivityTaskManager: START ChooserActivity. But after making a selection, nothing started and no error reported

Comment: @mamoman Any solution on this...facing similar kind of issue...any help would be much appreciated!!!

Answer (score 4):

"Copy" probably is not an app but rather part of the share sheet itself, copying the item to the clipboard. I am not terribly surprised that they do not invoke your `IntentSender` for that scenario, because there is no component to report that the user chose. This is similar to if the user closes the share sheet via the BACK button. As [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#EXTRA_CHOSEN_COMPONENT_INTENT_SENDER) states, "Apps should not be written assuming that this callback will always occur."